# Modular arithmetic question...

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

What is the value of $187^2 \mod 100$?

Comment: What have you tried? This has been asked many times.

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. If you [edit] the question to show us what you tried and where you are stuck we may be able to help you. Until you do that you will probably get just votes to close and downvotes.

Comment: @EthanBolker: unfortunately, the question was answered, so the OP will continue to post such questions.

Answer (score 1):

$187\equiv-13\pmod{100}$, $(-13)^2\equiv69\pmod{100}$

Comment: Yep... as simple as that!

Comment: I am glad you want to help here. That said, I would rather people did not answer simple questions like this where the OP shows no effort of their own.

Comment: Sorry @EthanBolker, I will keep that in mind next time!